# How can I install kernel header files for Kali 1.1.0 (moto) "3.18.0-kali1-amd64"?

Tags: kali-linux, repository

I require the linux-headers to install vmware-tools but kali recently discontinued support for moto https://www.kali.org/news/kali-moto-eol/
They did leave up an old repository under the url http://old.kali.org/kali
But that mirror does not seem to have the header files.

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`

E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-amd64
```

All the information on google is outdated because the repository mirrors were only recently moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been searching solutions for this problem until your quertion inspire me.By simply adding

```
deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
```

to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and
    apt-get update
then

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Now we find the kernel headers file of the old version!
[image]
However a new problem arise.As my kali runs a gcc-4.9 where linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 depends on gcc-4.7,I can't install the headers,and I have a problem removing gcc-4.9 .
Try finding ways...

Comment: Sorry I can no longer help, I got too frustrated and ending up upgrading to Kali 2.0 (sana)

Comment: That's fine. Thx anyway